# Using multiple Microsoft.Extension.Logging ILoggers in Prism Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism, ilogger

I have a xamarin.forms app using Prism.   However I need to add several microsoft.extensions.logging ILoggers to it. In the standard microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection setup for logging I would normally do

```
serviceCollection.AddLogging(builder =>
                        {
                                builder.AddDebug();
                                builder.AddConsole();

                                builder.AddApplicationInsights(someKey);
                        });
```

How would I do this with Prism?  Will I still be able to get a typed ILogger? e.g.

`public ThingieService(ILogger<ThingieService> logger)`

Answer (score 2):

There's a cool little plugin called [`Prism.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Extensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Extensions) that I find useful for this.

In your `RegisterTypes` method you can register services using the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` version of `IServiceCollection`. You can add support for the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` `ILogger` here. For example:

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
{
    protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
    {
        containerRegistry.RegisterServices(s =>
        {
            s.AddLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.AddSimpleConsole();
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This also works for other `IServiceCollection` extensions, such as `AddHttpClient()` or `ConfigureOptions()`.

Comment: which version of prism does it work with?

Comment: Got this working with Prism.Unity v8.0.0.1909 and Prism.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.Extensions v8.0.62. I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work with Xamarin Forms though.